# jquery datepicker show legenda below months

Tags: jquery, datepicker

In my datepicker i use some collors to show that a date is occupied or not available. I want to show an explenation of the collors below the months of the datepickers but in the pop-up. Is there a way to put a div below the pop-up of the datepicker? The dates/moths wil shift up a bit, but i can explain my colors....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but perhaps you could use jquery and do something like this...

```
$('div#ui-datepicker-div').append('<div>my legend html</div>')
```

obviously you'd need to style it up as well.